# ImageIO.createImageInputStream Keeps Returning null

Tags: java, javax.imageio

Hey all,
Whenever I try to get an `ImageInputStream` object using `ImageIO.createImageInputStream` it simply returns `null` with no exceptions, warnings or errors. I have tried passing different data types to the function, a simple `File`, and an `InputStream`, but both returned `null` also. The documentation says that if no suitable `ImageInputStreamSpi` is found then the function will return `null`, but the file is a bog-standard JPEG, and surely Java comes with a service provider for such a format out of the box?
Thanks for your time.

```
/**
 * Reads in an image from a file and returns the image in a
 * {@code BufferedImage} object.
 *
 * @param source the file to create the {@code BufferedImage}
 * from.
 * @return the {@code BufferedImage} object representing the image
 * in {@code source}.
 */
private BufferedImage readImage( File source ) {
    // There is only one image in this file
    final int imageIndex = 0;
    BufferedImage image = null;

    try {
        // Get the ImageReader object for this filetype
        Iterator readers =
            ImageIO.getImageReaders( source );
        ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) readers.next();

        // Create an ImageInputStream object from the source image file
        ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream( source );
        // Raises IllegalArgumentException, because iis is null
        reader.setInput( iis, true );

        // Read the image file
        image = reader.read( imageIndex );
    } catch ( Exception exception ) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        System.exit( -1 );
    }

    return image;
}
```

Comment: well clean your code and post it here so we can help :)

Comment: Except, you didn't answer my question, you just gave me a different solution which I was already using before, as detailed below... My original question, which I'm still having trouble with, is still left unanswered...

Comment: I have the same problem. For some reason it works on MacOSX 1.6 from within Eclipse but fails on production which is a debian linux environment. My app is an OSGI based webapp built on Equinox and Jetty servlet container. from all i read so far it seems to be related to JAI and OSGI (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493199/running-jai-in-osgi) . But I haven't solved it yet.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you doing all that??
you can simply do this:

```
image = ImageIO.read(source);
```

No `Iterators`, `ImageInputStreams`... no nothing !

**EDIT**: Since you insist, your code is not working because you're sending a `File` to `ImageIO.getImageReaders()` instead of a `ImageInputStream`. SO your code should look something like that:

```
ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(source);
Iterator readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(iis);
ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) readers.next();

reader.setInput(iis, false);
image = reader.read(imageIndex);
```

Comment: I was using `ImageIO.read` originally, but for big files, instead of just stalling when a big image was being read, I wanted to add the functionality to add observers to my `ImageReader` to track how much of the file had been read.

Comment: Okay, I've edited my code to what you've outlined, but the same problem still persists; `ImageIO.createImageInputStream` just returns `null` instead of a valid `ImageInputStream`, so this is kicking up an `IllegalArgumentException` in `ImageIO.getImageReaders` instead of in `ImageReader::setInput`.

Comment: From the Javadocs of `ImageIO.createImageInputStream(Object input)` it says that "input should be an Object to be used as an input source, such as a File, readable RandomAccessFile, or InputStream". This method throws an `IllegalArgumentException` if input is `null`! So make sure you're not passing null in the parameter `source`.

Comment: That's my problem, the `source` parameter is definitely not `null`, is an image `File`, but `ImageIO.createImageInputStream` still silently returns `null` without raising any exceptions, it's whatever functions that try to use the `ImageInputStream` afterwards that raise the exception. I have outlined in the original question how the documentation explains `ImageIO.createImageInputStream` returning `null`. Thanks for all your help so far.