# null returned while converting data array to ImageInputStream

Tags: java, image

I don't understand why **bigInputStream** is null, even if **data** is set well.

```
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    BufferedImage bufferedImage;
    bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(in);
    // next instruction has problem
    ImageInputStream bigInputStream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(bufferedImage);
    Iterator<ImageReader> iter = ImageIO.getImageReaders(bigInputStream);
    if (!iter.hasNext()) {
        // thow exception here
    }
    ImageReader reader = iter.next();
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130553/imageio-createimageinputstream-keeps-returning-null

Comment: @AnubianNoob use Debug, and I found bigInputStream instance is equal to null. No exception thrown.

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg.. Not really a duplicate. In that link, it convert a File to ImageInputStream and not a data array.

Comment: What are you attempting to do with the image input stream part? I see you begin with a buffered image which you created from a byte array, and then what is it you're doing after that (big picture)?

Comment: From @pwillig "Are you sure bufferedImage contains data? If ImageIO.read(in) isn't finding data to set to bufferedImage, that could be your problem."

Comment: @PaulRichter I try to get the image Format : PNG, JPG,...

Comment: @peeskillet I commented to your answer.

Comment: @Julia Ok. Where does the byte array data come from? Is it being generated dynamically in the program, or are you loading it from a file?

Comment: As far as I know (and others can correct me if I'm wrong), by the time you have a `BufferedImage` object in memory in your Java application, the original file format (png, jpg, etc) is irrelevant. If the data is coming from a file, then [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11447113/877472) might be most relevant.

Comment: @PaulRichter. Yes, I've tried a JPG and PNG files, but both of them giving me the same problem. I can't pass directly the files to the function "createImageInputStream". This snippet should be encapsulated in a function whose argument is byte[].

Comment: @PaulRichter, having byte[] as an input is mandatory. Except if you can advice me a snippet that would give me the desired result. I found some libraries by they are only SNAPSHOTS ( not allowed in the project..).

Comment: @Julia Ok I am assuming now that this is an assignment, and what you've described is one of the requirements or limitations your professor has imposed, yes? The problem of losing the format after you've created the buffered image still exists; there's no way to get that info without having access to the file object, or at least the URL to the file. I can't advise without seeing a bigger picture though. Can you edit the question and post the full method where this code lives, as well as the method that calls it? I need to see exactly where your `data` byte array is coming from and how its made.

Comment: @PaulRichter, I could get the format using the method defined in my answer. Maybe it has some drawbacks?

Comment: @Julia That appears to make sense to me. If it works, I don't see any drawbacks. The byte array itself I guess is the exact byte information as it existed in the original file, which would still contain the format information in its header.

Answer (score 3):

To try to answer the question, the problematic line is (as OP points out herself):

```
ImageInputStream bigInputStream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(bufferedImage);
```

(Small print: It's theoretically possible for this to work, but it requires custom service providers that could read image data from an image you already have loaded in memory, which seems a little odd).

It should probably be:

```
ImageInputStream bigInputStream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(in);
```

I.e.: An `ImageInputStream` is a helper class for `ImageReader`s to read binary data from a `File`, `InputStream`, `FileChannel` etc. It's not for reading data from an already constructed image.

After that fix, your code could look something like this:

```
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
ImageInputStream bigInputStream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(in);

Iterator<ImageReader> iter = ImageIO.getImageReaders(bigInputStream);
if (!iter.hasNext()) {
    // thow exception here
}
ImageReader reader = iter.next();

BufferedImage bufferedImage = reader.read(0); // Read the first image in the file

// Do other tings with reader, like getting the file format
String format = reader.getFormatName();
...

reader.dispose(); // Should be done in finally block, but I leave that out
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, the perfectly working method that I found in [this link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1263871?start=0&tstart=0) :

```
private static String determineImageFormat( byte[] imageBytes ) throws IOException {

  final ByteArrayInputStream bStream = new ByteArrayInputStream( imageBytes );

  final ImageInputStream imgStream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream( bStream );
  final Iterator<ImageReader> iter = ImageIO.getImageReaders( imgStream );

  final ImageReader imgReader = iter.next();

  return imgReader.getFormatName();
```

}

Likely, some verifications should be added.